# Querying a url in nodejs using connect.query()

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, node.js-connect

Hi I have a url of format

```
> http://127.0.0.1:3000/sss?AP=API&SE=AU
```

I used to follow the below code to query

```
var data=req.query[AP]
```

But now my url is

```
> http://127.0.0.1:3000/sss/API/AU
```

I am stuck as how to query this data.Any help regarding this will be much helpful.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
var parse = require('connect').utils.parseUrl;
var pathname = parse(req).pathname;

var data = pathname.split('/');
// data[2] => API
// data[3] => AU
```

or

```
var parse = require('connect').utils.parseUrl;
var pathname = parse(req).pathname;

var data = pathname.match(/\/sss\/(\w+)\/(\w+)/)
if (data) {
  // data[1] => API
  // data[2] => AU
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is using the routing of express.

With something like this, you'll get your values directly in the `req.params` object:

```
var app   = require('express').express();

app.get( "/sss/:AP/:SE", function( req, res ) {
    console.log( req.params.AP, req.params.SE );
});
```

Best regards
   Robert